# new angular module creation error

Tags: angular, npm, angular-module

few days back I started learning Angular 4 from scratch. After gaining some ideas I started to design a module for npm. I have designed the module and after that I followed this [medium.com](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/how-to-build-and-publish-an-angular-module-7ad19c0b4464) article and followed every step.
npm install data-formss  --- for getting dependency

[github](https://github.com/shabyWoks/data-form) link for project

Now the problem is when I used this dependency in the project

```
<data-form [input-parameter]= "data" [post-url]="url"></data-form>
```

where

```
data = [
    { type: 1, labelName: 'UserName: ', placeHolder: 'Username', inputProp: { type: 'text', id: 'username', minLen: "4", maxLen: "15", notAllowed: "$" }, validationText: "Looks Good!", inValidationText: "Enter Something" },
    { type: 1, labelName: 'Password: ', placeHolder: 'Password', inputProp: { type: 'password', id: 'pass', minLen: "4", maxLen: "15", notAllowed: "$" }, validationText: "Looks Good!", inValidationText: "Enter Something" },
    { type: 2, labelName: 'Gender: ', inputProp: { type: '', id: 'gender' }, options: [{ value: '0', key: 'Male' }, { value: '1', key: 'Female' }], inValidationText: "You forgot to mark something" , inline : false, mandatory: 1, noInOneLine: 1 },
    { type: 3, labelName: 'Gender: ', inputProp: { type: '', id: 'gender' }, options: [{ value: '0', key: 'Male' }, { value: '1', key: 'Female' }], inline : true, noInOneLine: 1 },
    { type: 4, labelName: 'Comment: ', inputProp: { type: '', id: 'comment', rowSize: '2' }, inValidationText: "Enter Something" },
    //{ type: 5, labelName: 'Image: ', inputProp: { type: '', id: 'image' }, inValidationText: "Enter Something" },
    { type: 6, labelName: 'Location: ', inputProp: { type: '', id: 'location' }, options: [{ value: '0', key: 'Chennai' }, { value: '1', key: 'Mumbai' }], inline : false, inValidationText: "Select Something" },
  ];
url= "someurl";
```

I am getting error as

```
zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:4200/data-form.component.html 404 (Not Found)
```

and similar error for every other component available.
Can anyone help me with this?

Updated

Build Tools
typescript, via the Angular compiler (ngc), for transpiling,
rollupjs for packaging,
uglify-js for minifying.

For project tree structure please check github link.

N.B. Readme file in github is yet to be completed.

Comment: the compiler when instantiating your component, try to fetch the template of your component and can't find it. What is your building tool? could you add the tree structure of your built application?

Comment: @Pierre Mallet please check github link for project structure.